# Where can i find Type Definitions Files (*.d.ts) for Amazon Cognito Identity SDK and how can i used them

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, angular2-services, amazon-cognito

Where can i find Type Definitions Files (*.d.ts) for Amazon Cognito Identity SDK? and how can i used them.

I'm using TypeScript for Angular2 and i want to have the code assistant ready to use, when i implement "AWS Cognito". I already use `import AWS = require("aws-sdk");` for the "aws-sdk" but i cant find a way to import the clases for "amazon Cognito Identity SDK". I already search in [definitelytyped](http://definitelytyped.org/)

Note: I already know that i can declare a global variable of type "any" but what i want its the utility of the code assistant.

**UPDATE:** "aws-sdk" and "amazon Cognito Identity SDK" are different and have different classes.

**Update 2:** I'm trying to implement this code:

```
AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';

var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : '...', // your user pool id here
    ClientId : '...' // your app client id here
};
var userPool = 
new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : '...', // your username here
    Pool : userPool
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked in the npm and I find it  [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-sdk),

you can install it :

```
npm install @types/aws-sdk
```

Comment: Can you write an example on how i should import it in my *.ts service? so i can have the code assistant ready with the classes of "amazon Cognito Identity SDK"

Comment: try this `import * as AWS  from 'aws-sdk'`

Comment: Thanks @Bougarfaoui El houcine but i'm trying to implement this code here: `AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
     
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : '...', // your user pool id here
    ClientId : '...' // your app client id here
};
var userPool = 
new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : '...', // your username here
    Pool : userPool
};`

Comment: sorry I didn't use this before.

Comment: It's ok, Thanks anyway, if i find an answer i will share it. the way you implement the import of "aws-sdk" was great though.